# Fonts in Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, fonts

I would like to know if there is a way to install new fonts in Ubuntu Touch without making the image writable.

I want to use this [emoji-set](https://github.com/eosrei/emojione-color-font), because I don't like the original emojis. On my desktop machine it works but on my phone (Meizu MX4) it says that the base font was not found.

May [custom images](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Customization) help me and if so, how do they work? I am using OTA 10.1.